# Get values from a promise with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, get, promise

I have this code:

```
      const { username, password, provider } = this;
  login(username, password, provider, (err) => {
    this.signingIn = false;

    if (err) {
      this.hasError = true;
    }

    const { $route, $router } = this;

    let redirect = '/';
    if ($route.query.redirect !== undefined) {
      redirect = $route.query.redirect;
    }

    $router.push(redirect);
    this.errors = err.response.json();
    var a = this.errors;
    console.log(a);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
  });
```

when I see the console from the navigator, the Output is:

```
Promise {<resolved>: {…}}
  __proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]]: Objecterrors: Array(1)
    0: 
      code:"validation.required"
      detail:"password is required"
      where:"request.body.password"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: 
Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

I just receive a Promise Object, I just want get the value from 'code' or 'detail' or 'where' in a console.log()

If I try with stringify I just get two keys {}

Do you know a special method or, which is the way to get this values??

Comment: Clearly, the return value of `err.response.json()` is a Promise. So you have to consume the promise. See the linked question and [MDN's documentation on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thank you @T.J Crowder  the promise was not solved, because give this message, I try use then to solve the promise and voalá, the next result was a array, tk

        a.then((res) => {
          console.log(res)
        })